# Get selected row id in quasar framework datatables

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I want to delete row from quasar-framework datatable, so I want to pass selected row(s) id to a delete function to be able to make axios request to delete data with these id(s), but I don't know how to pass these id(s) to my delete function. How to get only selected id ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add selection properties, for example `<q-table :data="tableData" :selection="single" :selected.sync="selectedRow">` on q-table and in data function add property `selectedRow = []`. In this property you will have array index of selected row from `tableData`.